# ¿Por qué botón no inserta a la base de datos en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos, .net

Saludos. Tengo una clase llamada Registro, esta clase está relacionada a una clase llamada funciones que contiene valores booleanos llamados registrar, eliminar, actualizar.

Creé constructores, y luego dentro de la clase "registrar", abrí mi base de datos y puse mi código para insertar los campos. Luego en el botón del formulario instanceé mi clase con los nombres de los botones, pero cuando pulso el botón simplemente no sucede nada. Me podrían decir que estoy haciendo mal.

//CODIGO

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1.Clases
    {
class Registro : Ifunciones
{
    public string cedula { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string apellido { get; set; }
    public string telefono { get; set; }
    public string direccion { get; set; }

    //Constructor sin parametros
    public Registro(){

        }
    //Constructor con parametros
        public Registro(string _cedula, string _nombre, string _apellido, string _telefono, string _direccion)
    {
        this.cedula = _cedula;
        this.nombre = _nombre;
        this.apellido = _apellido;
        this.telefono = _telefono;
        this.direccion = _direccion;

    }

    public bool actualizar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool eliminar()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool registrar()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SP_REGISTRO";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEDULA", cedula);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", nombre);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDO", apellido);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEFONO", telefono);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRECCION", direccion);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Se inserto correctamente");
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                cn.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

//BOTON DEL FORMULARIO

```
     private void btm_agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            var registrar = new Clases.Registro(txtCedula.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text, txtTelefono.Text, txtDireccion.Text);



    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tu botón solo instancia la clase. te falta llamar al proceso que quieras (registrar por ejemplo). Ese es tu problema?

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, dentro de unos minutos haré el recorrido.

Si instancio la clase bool registrar() se queda sin los parametros que le agregue arriba y me los pide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día.

En `//BOTON DEL FORMULARIO` solo estas instanciando la clase (es un llamado al construtor); tienes dos constructores para `Registro` uno con o otro sin parámetros.

Conforme a lo que pussiste prueba como a continuación coloco:

```
private void btm_agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   var registrar = new Clases.Registro(txtCedula.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text, txtTelefono.Text, txtDireccion.Text); /* Este es un constructor que estas usando no es llamada a método para realizar acción a la BD */

   registrar.registrar(); /* puedes ponerlo con if para mostrar o hacer algo en caso que sí y/o no guardo.*/

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Crea una clase para realizar las operaciones CRUD (create, update y delete), en lugar de crearlo todo en una sola clase, la clase que vas a crear debe de ser publica, con sets y gets hechos a medida, y en la clase donde tengas el botón haces un llamado a esta clase, la construyes de nuevo y utilizas los sets que creaste, puede verse como más trabajo pero tendrás el control de todo el procedimiento de registrar, y si lanza algún error podrás depurar paso a paso y encontrarás más fácil tu error, los gets que coloqué es opcional, si quieres volcar los datos a una lista para utilizarlos en otro formulario puedes usarlos entonces, si no es el caso no es necesario que los escribas, esta sería la clase que crearías...

```
public class Registro_crud
    {
        private string cedula;
        private string nombre;
        private string apellido;
        private string telefono;
        private string direccion;
        //esta es la variable que retornará el mensaje del procedimiento insertar
        string mensaje;

        public Registro_crud()
        {

        }

        public Registro_crud(string cedula, string nombre, string apellido, string telefono, string direccion)
        {
            this.cedula = cedula;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.telefono = telefono;
            this.direccion = direccion;
        }

        //Sets y gets
        public void setCedula(string ced) { this.cedula = ced; }
        public void setNombre(string nom) { this.nombre = nom; }
        public void setTelefono(string tele) { this.telefono = tele; }
        public void setDireccion(string dire) { this.direccion = dire; }

        public string getCedula() { return (this.cedula); }
        public string getNombre() { return (this.nombre); }
        public string getTelefono() { return (this.telefono); }
        public string getDireccion() { return (this.direccion); }

        //Procedimiento de insertar, crea el procedimiento que te retorne un string en vez de un valor boleano
         public string registrar()
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SP_REGISTRO";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEDULA", cedula);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", nombre);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDO", apellido);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEFONO", telefono);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRECCION", direccion);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                return "Los datos se guardaron con éxito";
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Luego en el formulario donde está tu botón llamas a la clase registro...

```
private void btm_agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Registro_crud reg = new Registro_crud();
        reg.setCedula(txtCedula.Text);
        reg.setNombre(txtNombre.Text);
        reg.setTelefono(txtTelefono.Text);
        reg.setDireccion(txtDireccion.Text);
        reg.registrar();
        string mensaje;
        mensaje = reg.registrar();
        MessageBox.SHow(mensaje);
    }
```